# Identify pages a specific source medium and channel clicked into

Tags: google-analytics

Our email vendor has a product recommendation engine that assigns products to an outgoing email 'intelligently'.  Unfortunately they do not have very robust reporting on what sku's were actually clicked.  I've exhausted their options and I am forced to turn to Google Analytics.

First I created a Segment using the Source, Medium and Campaign to limit traffic.

Then I loaded that segment into Behavior/Site Content/Landing Page and applied a search regexp for just the /product/ pages. Since there are no other products displayed in those emails, the product recommendation links should be the only remaining pages...

Instead I find myself looking at all sorts of product pages including some that have markers that can only exist from other email campaigns and events like product searches which are not links that would be present in the original email.

How do I filter down to a distinct list of links that were clicked into from that email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

In my segment I had the option 'Filter Users' selected in the Traffic Sources tab.  When I changed it to 'Filter Sessions' all (well mostly all) the random page views seem to have disappeared.

I think when 'Filter Users' was set, GA found all users that had clicked on those links and all the sessions started by those users.  The Landing Page report used the fully expanded session list to pull all the landing pages those users had clicked on.

When I changed it to 'Filter Sessions' then only the sessions that contained that landing page directly were fed into the Landing Pages report.

Assuming there can only be 1 landing page per session I should have the list of pages I was looking for.

Comment: Your understanding of User versus Session filtering in segments is exactly right - it sounds (from the outside) like you did find the explanation and now have the data you wanted.